# SQL for finding the counts per user

Tags: sql, count, distinct

Lets say I have the following table:

```
Student      Course           University
1             a                   x
1             b                   x
1             c                   x
1             a                   y
2             a                   x
2             a                   y
2             a                   z
3             a                   x
```

For each student, I am trying to find the number of unique courses and universities that they are enrolled in.

The output would be as follows:

```
Student     No. of Courses        No. of Universities
 1             3                         2
 2             1                         3
 3             1                         1
```

How would I construct the SQL for this?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @rekha . . . Do you really want the number of courses for "2" to be "1"?  Each course is the same regardless of university?

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT Student,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Course)     AS NumberOfCourses,
       COUNT(DISTINCT University) AS NumberOfUniversities
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY Student
```

Comment: Argh. 21 seconds too slow. +1

Comment: nice, simple, it works, and even i can understand it :)